# How to submit a form using httpurlconnection?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, httpurlconnection

The form which I want to submit is of the following format

```
<form class=loginForm name="LoginForm" onSubmit="return loginSubmit();"
    method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <ol>



<li><span class="instruction">Please login with your User Name and Password.</span></li>

        <li><a tabIndex=2 target="_blank"
            href="/portal/site/login/en-gb/help.html"
            class="assistance redArrow">Need help with logging in?</a>
        </li>
        <li><label for="username">User Name</label> <input tabIndex=3
            class="authInput" type="text" id="username" name="username"
            autocomplete="off" class="authInput" /></li>
        <li><label for="password">Password</label> <input tabIndex=4
            type="password" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="off"
            class="authInput" /></li>

        <li class="persist"><label for="secureComputer"> <input type="checkbox"
                value="1" tabIndex="5" name="rememberMe" id="secureComputer"
                 /><span style="padding-left:10px;">I am on a secure computer.</span>
                <br><span style="margin-left: 23px; font-size: 10px;">(Only check if this computer is secure and is only used by you.)</span>
        </label></li>
    </ol>   


                    <a tabIndex=6
            href="/IDM/pwdservice?a=fp"
            class="assistance redArrow">Forgotten your Password?</a><br>

                <input tabIndex=7 type="submit"
            value="Login"
            class="redBtn"/><br>

</fieldset>
</form>



<form   name="Login"  onsubmit="" action="/IDM/UI/Login"  method="post" style="display:none">
    <input type="hidden" name="IDToken1" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="IDToken2" value="">  
    <input type="hidden" name="IDButton" value="Log In">
    <input type="hidden" name="gotoOnFail" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="encoded" value="true">
    <input type="hidden" name="service" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="stepUp" value="N">
    <input type="hidden" name="currLang" value="en">
    <input type="hidden" name="gx_charset" value="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="rememberMe" value="N">
```

I am trying to proceed in the same ways as mentioned [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/). Here is how I am proceeding:

```
 URL server = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection) server.openConnection();
        urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConn.setDoInput(true);
        urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
        DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream (urlConn.getOutputStream());
        if (parameters != null)
            printout.writeBytes (parameters);
        printout.flush();
        printout.close();
```

where `parameters` is of the form `name1=value1&name2=value2.....&username=uname&password=pwd`

However the problem is that I want to add param name and its value for the **Login** (tabindex=7) ,as shown in the above mentioned [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/), input as well but I do not have a name only its value?

Is there another way to submit such form to login into a website? There is *loginSubmit* function on the HTML page, is there a way to use that for `urlConn`.

Comment: java is not the same as javascript

Comment: Sorry for the carelessness, tags corrected!! Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Use Selenium or WebDriver to do such things. In most cases this is really hard work to achieve this with plain Java and HUC.